# Low voltage LED bulb or jump into line voltage?

Tags: voltage, led, ac, hobbyist

I'm not even sure if this is appropriate StackExchanage community for this but I wasn't sure where else this sort of question would fit.

So I tinker with electronics here and there and primarily it has been with DC power (batteries for the most part). I have in a mind project for a simple dimming lamp and I would like to use it introduce myself to AC power although I'm unclear about a few things. The basics of the project I have in mind requires a power source, a dimmer, and a light bulb but I'm struggling to figure out if I should go with an AC adapter as the power source (a wall wart) and use a low voltage dimmer/LED bulb (12V or something of the like) or just dive into full line voltage using the proper dimmer/LED bulb.

I understand that line voltage is more dangerous but it does remove the bulky wall wart and the require for low voltage components. I'm looking to use a LED bulb that imitates an Edison style bulb I don't think I have found one that is more low voltage use (I could simply be mistaken).

Would it be a large pain to do this using an AC adapter and much simpler to use the line voltage provided by my house? Lastly, are there any good resources I could look at around tackling projects when using AC power (especially higher voltages and amps as are provided by households)?

Thanks again and sorry for the odd question.

Comment: Well, you can't learn about something unless you decide to do it. Working with line voltage is entirely safe so long as you learn about appropriate safety, which is kind of oxymoronic ("safe if you don't do anything dangerous") but it's not hard. Just keep it isolated from potential touch by yourself and others. At low currents, it's the volts rather than the bang that is dangerous. Heck, I've had quite a few 240V shocks, and I'm still here. If a bit burnt around the edges.

Comment: A couple of random thoughts: not all LEDs are dimmable - check the ones you are thinking of buying.  If you're using any sort of touch-sensitive circuit, make sure there is a substantial resistance between the user and the circuit - such as two resistors in series, each of which has a high enough voltage rating and resistance to protect the user if the circuit malfunctions.

Comment: Need more info on your goals to answer. Are you designing an LED dimmer?